# Meaning of preposition in the following context

Tags: prepositions

> It is highly creditable **for** him to have risen to eminence from poverty and obscurity.

What does the preposition exactly mean here?

Thanks in advance,........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence can be re-written as:

> It is highly creditable **that he has risen** to eminence from poverty and obscurity.